# Epson XP-400 won't print says "offline"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer

My Epson XP-400 was working and printing just fine.  Wireless lights on router and printer are lit.

Suddenly the `-- cannot print --` message says the printer is offline. I tried everything I could think of:  reset router, tried to manually reset Wi-Fi on printer.  Looked everywhere to see if the IP address or gateways were changed somehow. This appears to have happened after a Windows 8 update.

Comment: Have you checked the printer queue? You might have some stuck jobs. You can get to the printer queue via the Devices and Printers option in the Control Panel.

Comment: Since you mentioned Windows 8, is this related to a specific computer? Or all computers on the network? Can you connect the computer in question with a USB cable to see if that works? How about System Restore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

It's likely the printer got assigned another IP address. Try considering a static address or pre-allocated IP in your wireless router for the printer so this surprise can be avoided.

For your client to find the printer again, it's easily done by removing and adding the printer again.

It's not likely the windows update caused this.

It's always a nice day.

Comment: A DHCP Reservation fixed my home wifi printer headaches years ago.

Comment: Same for me, i'm all sorted. This is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to use a different port; specifically the Standard TCP/IP port.  If you are using Windows 10 you'll need to do the following:

1. Got to Devices and Printers (just type printer in the ask me box)
2. Right click on the printer and select Printer Properties
3. Select the Port tab
4. Give it the IP address of the printer and let the system do the rest.

It should work. Also, you should consider giving your printer a static IP address.